# How can I send messages to a remote actor via CLI with Akka remoting?

Tags: scala, akka, command-line-interface, akka-remote-actor, akka-remoting

I have a remote actor, `Bar` and a local actor, `Foo`. I want to use `Foo` to pass messages to `Bar` on each invocation of a CLI.

`Bar` can be passed messages successfully, but `Foo` hangs while waiting for a message. To fix this, I added a `sys.exit(0)` at the end of `Foo`'s main. This causes an association issue with `Foo`'s system.

How can I shut down my local actor between successive CLI issuances without killing my local actor manually?

## Shut up and give me the code!

---

## Foo:

> ## `build.sbt`

```
name := "Foo"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.11"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-remote" % "2.4.11"
libraryDependencies += "com.github.scopt" %% "scopt" % "3.5.0"

fork in run := true
```

> ## `Main.scala`

```
import akka.actor._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

case class Config(mode: String = "", greeting: String="")

class Foo extends Actor {
  // create the remote actor
  val BarActor = context.actorSelection("akka.tcp://BarSystem@127.0.0.1:2552/user/BarActor")

  def receive = {
    case method: String => BarActor ! method
  }
}

object CommandLineInterface {

  val config = ConfigFactory.load()
  val system = ActorSystem("FooSystem", config.getConfig("FooApp"))

  val FooActor = system.actorOf(Props[Foo], name = "FooActor")

  val parser = new scopt.OptionParser[Config]("Foo") {
    head("foo", "1.x")

    help("help").text("prints usage text")

    opt[String]('m', "method").action( (x, c) =>
      c.copy(greeting = x) ).text("Bar will greet with <method>")
  }
}

object Main extends App {
  import CommandLineInterface.{parser, FooActor}

  parser.parse(args, Config()) match {
    case Some(config) => FooActor ! config.greeting
    case None => sys.error("Bad news...")
  }
  /* 
    When sys.exit(0) commented, this hangs and Bar greet.
    When sys.exit(0) uncommented, this doesn't hang, but also Bar doesn't greet.
   */
 
  //sys.exit(0)
}
```

> ## application.conf

```
FooApp {
  akka {
    loglevel = "INFO"
    actor {
      provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
    }
    remote {
      enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
      netty.tcp {
        hostname = "127.0.0.1"
        port = 0
      }
      log-sent-messages = on
      log-received-messages = on
    }
  }
}
```

---

## Bar:

> ## build.sbt

```
name := "Bar"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.11"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-remote" % "2.4.11"
```

> ## Main.scala

```
import akka.actor._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

class Bar extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case greeting: String => Bar.greet(greeting)
  }
}

object Bar {
  val config = ConfigFactory.load()
  val system = ActorSystem("BarSystem", config.getConfig("BarApp"))
  val BarActor = system.actorOf(Props[Bar], name = "BarActor")

  def greet(greeting: String) = println(greeting)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    /* Intentionally empty */
  }
}
```

> ## application.conf

```
BarApp {
  akka {
    loglevel = "INFO"
    actor {
      provider = remote
    }
    remote {
      enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
      netty.tcp {
        hostname = "127.0.0.1"
        port = 2552
      }
      log-sent-messages = on
      log-received-messages = on
    }
  }
}
```

Run `Foo` with `sbt 'run-main Main -m hello'`, and run `Bar` with `sbt 'run-main Main'`.

Sorry for the long code, but it's the MVCE for my problem.

How can I achieve my desired behavior -- the CLI actor dies between successive CLI invocations with the remote actor waiting for new messages.

Comment: Why do you think that `Bar` died? Is there something in the log indicating this?

Comment: @PawełBartkiewicz I tried to clear up my meaning. Sorry for the misspeak. :) Hopefully it's more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you call `sys.exit(0)` immediately after sending a message to `FooActor`, so there's a significant chance that the application exits before `FooActor` gets the chance to even read the message, let alone forward it to `BarActor`.

There seem to be [many possible solutions](http://letitcrash.com/post/30165507578/shutdown-patterns-in-akka-2), one of them being:

```scala
class Foo extends Actor {
  // create the remote actor
  val BarActor = context.actorSelection("akka.tcp://BarSystem@127.0.0.1:2552/user/BarActor")

  override def receive = {
    case method: String => {
      BarActor ! method
      self ! PoisonPill
    }
  }

  override def postStop = {
    context.system.terminate
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, it turns out that the system still gets shut down before dispatching the message to `Bar`.

I couldn't find any reasonable solution to this issue if you want to send a message in a "fire and forget" style. However, in most cases, it's desirable to get some kind of response from the remote actor, so you could do:

```scala
class Foo extends Actor {
  // create the remote actor
  val BarActor = context.actorSelection("akka.tcp://BarSystem@127.0.0.1:2552/user/BarActor")

  override def receive = {
    case method: String => {
      BarActor ! method
      context.become(waitingToKillMyself)
    }
  }

  def waitingToKillMyself: Receive = {
    case response: String => {
      println(response)
      self ! PoisonPill
    }
  }

  override def postStop = {
    context.system.terminate
  }
}

// ...

object Main extends App {
  import CommandLineInterface.{parser, FooActor, system}
  import system.dispatcher

  parser.parse(args, Config()) match {
    case Some(config) => {
      FooActor ! config.greeting
      system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(10.seconds, FooActor, PoisonPill)
    }

    case None => sys.error("Bad news...")
  }
}
```

Bar:

```scala
class Bar extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case greeting: String => {
      Bar.greet(greeting)
      sender() ! "OK"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a solid solution if it's a one-time message, but I want `Bar` to basically always be waiting for a message. Will this achieve that end?

Comment: Isn't `BarSystem` a separate actor system?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your comment after edit. Yes, I believe this should work fine (can't try this myself right now, I can do it later if you want). Since `FooSystem` and `BarSystem` are separate actor systems, `shutdown` or `terminate` should stop `FooSystem` only ([documentation](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/index.html#akka.actor.ActorSystem@terminate():scala.concurrent.Future[akka.actor.Terminated])).

Comment: I've added your answer and I'm finding that `Bar` isn't receiving my messages, but `Foo` is receiving the `"Done"` message anyway. I'm also getting dead-letters messages along with `Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.`. I'll dig a bit into that.

Comment: @erip Edited my answer, this solution seems cleaner, hopefully it will also work better. I'll try this myself when I get a chance.

Comment: @erip You're right, for some reason Akka won't dispatch the message before shutting down the system. That's probably because there are separate queues for local and remote actors, so local PoisonPill gets sent first. It would be nice if Akka had some method to flush all pending messages before terminating.

Comment: How do you know you have flushed all messages?

Comment: @ViktorKlang As an Akka user? There's no way as far as I know, but considering you're working on Akka I guess you know better. So you're asking in the context of akka-remote? You could check the TCP buffer. There's still no guarantee that the message was correctly parsed at the other end, but at least you did everything you could to ensure it was sent before shutting down the local system. Which still doesn't make sense in most cases. I'm not an expert on Akka internals, just read most of the docs, some source and using Akka from time to time.

Comment: My question was a leading one, since it all boils down to the 2 Generals problem. (Well, that and the fact that a message could hit the internal buffers at any point, in which case you need to have a timeout, but in any case you won't be sure)

Comment: @ViktorKlang Yes, I'm not saying this can be solved perfectly, but the Two Generals Problem affects everything, yet we do have such things as video streaming today and it works most of the time. If you assume that remote communication is always unreliable, then why create akka-remote in the first place? I'm only saying there's currently no way to send a fire-and-forget message and terminate the system afterwards with **any** hope of success. Which seems like a very rare scenario, so I fully understand that it may be not worth the effort.

Comment: Anyway, sorry if it sounded like I was criticizing Akka, it's a really great project and I understand the design decisions behind it. I'll happily continue the discussion somewhere else (SO chat, Github ticket?) if you'd like, maybe even get to know Akka's source code better and try to come up with a solution in my spare time, if you think it's worth our time. For me, it's a "nice to have" feature request, nothing critical.

Comment: In this case, just adding a bit of a delay before exiting is enough, it would be just as safe as any other solution I can think about :)

Comment: @ViktorKlang Yes, but then it would always cause the delay, right? Even if the message got processed very fast. I think waiting for the response (with a reasonable timeout) is much more efficient in most cases.

Comment: Absolutely, but both the request and the response can be lost. :) Two Generals and all. :) But yeah…